# Splitting sentence of phrases to array

Tags: php

I was wondering if there is a way to split a string of phrases to an array. Each phrase is surrounded by single quotation marks. I appreciate any suggestions!

What I tried

```
 explode(' ', $string);
```

Input

```
$string = "'Hello world' 'green apples' 'red grapes'";
```

Desired Output

```
  //ary[0] = 'Hello World'
  //ary[1] = 'green apples'
  //ary[2] = 'red grapes'
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you really tried this? Setting the $string variable as you have it would throw an error...

Comment: This isn't valid PHP `$string = 'Hello world' 'green apples' 'red grapes'` - update it so we can see what your code actually looks like

Comment: Do you mean $string = "'Hello world' 'green apples' 'red grapes'" ?

Comment: See edited, I apologize, I forgot to surround the string with double quotations in my example.

Answer (score 2):

After correcting your `$string` variable

```
$string = "'Hello world' 'green apples' 'red grapes'";
$arr = explode("' '", trim($string, "'"));
print_r($arr);
```

It'll output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Hello world
    [1] => green apples
    [2] => red grapes
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
$string = "'Hello world' 'green apples' 'red grapes'";

preg_match_all("/'[\w\s]+'/",$string,$match);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($match[0]);
```

Ref: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 'Hello world'
    [1] => 'green apples'
    [2] => 'red grapes'
)
```

Comment: You should use `*` instead of `+` in this regular expression if you allow to use empty strings.

Comment: @Prasanth Bendra, what is `$match`?

Comment: That is were the matches are stored, third parameter of preg_match_all